# linker error when running a simple hello world on Mac Mojave

Tags: c, macos

I am getting the following linker error:

Source (`hello_world.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   printf("hello world\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc hello_world.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$
```

Comment: On a Mac, `gcc` is (by default) a link to `clang`, so the error message mentioning `clang` isn't altogether surprising. On the face of it, the linker is telling you that the source file you compiled doesn't contain `main()`. What you show obviously does contain `main()`. You need to look again at `hello_world.c` (e.g. `cat hello_world.c`) because it would appear that you do not have the code you show in it.  For example, you might have an incomplete multiline comment that effectively erases the definition of `main()`.  Try adding `-Wall` to the compilation options: `gcc -Wall hello_world.c`.

Comment: Did you save the file in the editor before compiling it? Is the editor writing to the same directory as the working directory in the Terminal window where you executed gcc?

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I forgot to save the file in my editor.My bad.